# TF, access the filenames of the elements in a dataset object: dataset.group_by_window group by filename?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to train a network with "n" number of bodies of conv-nets, then concatenate the results and predict on the concatenated tensor.

For the training process, I want to feed the network batches of "n" number of elements. I've read the docs and found about the map() group_by_window() and window() methods. I want to group my training and validation data based on information contained in the filename of the images I'm feeding them, and this is where I'm struggling.

How do I access the filenames of the elements in a dataset object so that I can use it in the key_func passed to the group_by_window() method?

I create the dataset object using "image_dataset_from_directory", labels are inferred and categorical as my data is placed in subdirectories with the class names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property `file_paths` to the access the file names of your dataset:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

def preprocess_data(images, labels):
  file_paths = train_ds.file_paths
  # Do something with the file_paths
  # ...

  print(file_paths[:5])
  return images, labels
  
train_ds = train_ds.map(preprocess_data)
# or train_ds.group_by_window(*)
```

```
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.
['/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/daisy/7568630428_8cf0fc16ff_n.jpg',
 '/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/dandelion/7367491658_9eb4dc2384_m.jpg',
 '/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/tulips/18378582936_ee7085c850.jpg', 
 '/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/tulips/2426847695_4b8409402e_n.jpg', 
 '/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/roses/2949945463_366bc63079_n.jpg']
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to access these properties after applying the window() method? The resultant dataset is a tuple of _VariantDataset. I'm trying to use the window() method to group the data, then use a filter() to drop the windows based on the filenames, but i'm having trouble accessing the data in the _VariantDataset. If using file_paths on the whole windowed dataset, I get a AttributeError: 'WindowDataset' object has no attribute 'file_paths'

Comment: Could you perhaps ask a new question with more details and reproducible code?

Comment: just did, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70196122/tf-variantdataset-properties)