# TF, _VariantDataset properties

Tags: python, tensorflow

Continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70153151/tf-access-the-filenames-of-the-elements-in-a-dataset-object-dataset-group-by-w/70153363#70153363) issue.

I have a model with 'n' number of conv net bodies inside. This model will process images in sequence, as they come from a camera. For the training process, I need to feed the model the training data mimicking the final how it will work. I have a series of videos split into frames, and I want to create a sliding windows of 'n' number of frames to feed model. But I want to drop the windows that have frames from unrelated videos. To determine if the frames are from the same video, I intend to use the frame filename.

The first part (sliding window) can be achieved using the window() method, for the second my idea is to use the filter() method with a custom function.

The problem I am having is how to get the filename (or filepath) of the items in the windows. The objects returned by the method do not have the file_paths property.

Applying the [window()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) method to a dataset in TF returns a "WindowDataset" object. This object does not have the file_paths property, and contains tuples. In my case, these tuples are as follow:

```
[(<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
 (<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
...]
```

Here is my pseudocode:

```
training_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(training_data_dir,
                                                               shuffle=False,
                                                               label_mode='categorical',
                                                               batch_size=hyperparameters["BATCH_SIZE"],
                                                               image_size=IMG_SIZE)) 
# Returns a batched dataset, proceed to unbatch it
unb_training_dataset = training_dataset.unbatch()

# Window the unbatched dataset
win_train_dataset = unb_train_dataset.window(3, 
                                    shift=1, 
                                    stride=1,
                                    drop_remainder=True,
                                    )
# Check contents of the windowed dataset
list(win_train_dataset)

<output>:
[(<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
 (<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
 (<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
...
[(<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>),
 (<_VariantDataset shapes: (283, 577, 3), types: tf.float32>,
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (2,), types: tf.float32>)]
```

I also tried the example on the documentation:

```
for window in win_train_dataset:
  print([item.numpy() for item in window])
<output>:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_877/1363250068.py in <module>
      1 for window in win_train_dataset:
----> 2   print([item.numpy() for item in window])

/tmp/ipykernel_877/1363250068.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 for window in win_train_dataset:
----> 2   print([item.numpy() for item in window])

AttributeError: '_VariantDataset' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Your question should preferably be clear enough standing alone. Can you clarify what you are willing to achieve without resorting to linking another question? Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing, done